# PHP - file get content failed to open stream from URL

Tags: php

i have this piece of code which permits me to retrieve the information from a link... now, it says failed to open stream... here is the code:

Thanks!

```
$b = time ();
$date1 =date( "Y-m-d;h:i:s" , mktime(date("h")+6, date("i"), date("s"), date("m") , date("d"), date("Y")));
$str_time = "";
$str_msg = "";
$str_from = "";
$str_zip = "";

echo file_get_contents('href="http://testext.i-movo.com/api/receivesms.aspx?".$str_from."".$str_zip."".$phone."".$str_time."".$date1."".$str_msg.""');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
echo file_get_contents('href="http://testext.i-movo.com/api/receivesms.aspx?".$str_from."".$str_zip."".$phone."".$str_time."".$date1."".$str_msg.""');
```

Should be this:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://testext.i-movo.com/api/receivesms.aspx?".$str_from.$str_zip.$phone.$str_time.$date1.$str_msg);
```

Comment: You don't need to concatenate empty strings.

Comment: @SteveRobbins thanks for the edit i just removed the beginning and the end that was unnecessary i did not look for the empty strings

Answer (score 0):

please read the documentation for [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

the example says

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

you are using

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('href="http://www.example.com/');
```

now what is wrong ..